# Mail not sending from ewebguru domain Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a domain `techo.com` (bought from ewebguru) and I'm tryng to send mail from my rails app but mail is not sending I'm using following code configuration in production and development :

```
{
  :user => 'abcd@techo.com',
  :password => '*********',
  :domain => 'techo.com',
  :port => 25,
  :authentication => :none 
}
```

somebody suggest me to do these :

```
User: mail id
Password: mail id password
SMTP Server: tecorb.com
SMTP Port: 25
POP Port: 110
SSL Authentication:None
```

I'm not getting how  to configure these into my development.

Please suggest me.

Comment: You need to check whether port 25 is open on your local system or not. This issue has nothing to do with domain name provider. What type of error you are getting in the terminal.?

Comment: Thanks for response @abhinay. I don't have any error on terminal.

Comment: It's kind of tough without looking at the logs. Can you confirm that you have followed each steps like generating mailer, calling deliver_now on mailer class etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see your code, you are missing `:address` key in the configuration. Address for `ewebguru` is `mahanadi.ewebguru.net` (may be this address can be change but same for my domain purchased from ewebguru). Try configuration like this :

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'abcd@techo.com',
  :password => '*******',
  :server => 'techo.com',
  :address=>"mahanadi.ewebguru.net"
}
```

Hope this will work.